# Conditional probability of dependent events involving random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ ~ $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and  $Y$ ~ $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be two independent random variables with uniform and normal distributions, respectively. Define a new random variable $Z = (X-Y)^2$.

> How to compute the following conditional probability:
> $$P \left(Z \leq \frac{1}{2} ~\Big|~ \frac{1}{2} \leq X \leq 1, -1 \leq Y \leq 1\right)  ~?$$

**My try:**

I tried to apply the [Baye's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) but I have no idea how to compute the probability
$$P \left( \frac{1}{2}\leq X \leq 1, -1 \leq Y \leq 1 ~\Big|~ Z \leq \frac{1}{2}\right).$$ I think this probability can be even more complicated than that of the question.

I also know how to compute $P \left(\frac{1}{2} \leq X \leq 1, -1 \leq Y \leq 1\right)$ and $P \left(Z \leq \frac{1}{2}\right)$, but I stuck how to use them to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for any hint/idea.

Comment: Use the definition $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$.

Comment: @StefanHansen,  and for $P(A \cap B)$, what do you suggest?

Comment: Well, it turns out to be $P\big(\tfrac12\leqslant X\leqslant 1,X-\tfrac14\leqslant Y \leqslant \min(X+\tfrac14,1)\big)$ which you should be able to calculate as a double integral since you know the joint density of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: I got the idea, thanks! But $Z = (X-Y)^2$, not $Z = X-Y$. :)